# The method totalTax(PropertyTax) in the type PropertyTax is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote this code, but I can't understand where the problem is.

1.

```
package kiran;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class TestPropertytax {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    PropertyTax p1 = new PropertyTax(100000, 1.05);
    p1.calculate();
    print(p1, nf);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");

    PropertyTax p2 = new PropertyTax(150000, 1.05);
    p2.calculate();
    print(p2, nf);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Total tax revenue " + nf.format(PropertyTax.totalTax()));
    System.out.println("--------- End of report ----------");
  }

  static void print(PropertyTax p, NumberFormat nf)
  {
    System.out.println("Assessed value " + nf.format(p.getAssessedValue()));
    System.out.println("Taxable amount " + nf.format(p.getTaxableAmount()));
    System.out.println("Tax rate for each $100.00 is " + nf.format(p.getTaxRate()));
    System.out.println("Property tax is " + nf.format(p.getTax()));
  }
}
```

2.

```
package kiran;

public class PropertyTax {

  private double assessedvalue;

  private double taxrate;

  private static double taxableamount;

  private static double propertytax;
  //private static double totaltaxrevenue;

  public PropertyTax(double AssessedValue, double TaxRate)
  {
      assessedvalue = AssessedValue;
      taxrate = TaxRate;
      taxableamount = assessedvalue*.92;
      propertytax = taxableamount*(taxrate/100);
  }

  public double totalTax(PropertyTax pT)
  {
      return this.calculate() + pT.calculate();
  }

  public double calculate()
  {
      return propertytax = taxableamount*(taxrate/100);
  }

  public double getTax()
  {
      return propertytax;
  }

  public double getTaxableAmount()
  {
      return taxableamount;
  }

  public double getAssessedValue()
  {
      return assessedvalue;
  }

  public double getTaxRate()
  {
      return taxrate;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand it either.

Answer (score 0):

The method `totalTax` expects a `PropertyTax` argument and is an instance method, i.e.

```
System.out.println("Total tax revenue " + nf.format(PropertyTax.totalTax()));
```

should be

```
System.out.println("Total tax revenue " + nf.format(p1.totalTax(p2)));
                                                    ^           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

In `` `main(String[] args) `` you call `PropertyTax.totalTax()`. In PropertyTax.java, you define the method `totalTax` with the argument `pT`

You might want to replace `PropertyTax.totalTax()` with `p1.totalTax(p2)`

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.